# Reverse GeoCoding not working on blackberry

Tags: json, blackberry, geocoding, reverse

I am using Reverse Geocoding to get the location name. I debug on simulator and run the following query:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/geo?json&ll=-42.307546,-101.048116&sensor=false

And it results in the following result:

```json
{
  "name": "-42.307546,-101.048116",
  "Status": {
    "code": 602,
    "request": "geocode"
  }
}
```

It does not result in getting the location name for me. How can I find the location name? Please Help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: check this http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/geo?json&ll=12.9833,77.5833&sensor=false

Comment: when i click your link, its showing as {
  "Status": {
    "code": 610,
    "request": "geocode"
  }
}

Comment: insert correct coordinates values, then try.

Comment: It appears google detects if it is click request or browser request. If you refresh the page it will show same results showed in the question.

Comment: the values of latitude and longitude is on the south pacific ocean. So you didn't get the address........

Comment: https://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&q=-42.307546,-101.048116&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bpcl=35466521&biw=1366&bih=601&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=wl&authuser=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Status**: This includes the response code of the request, which is a simple way to determine what actually happened when the request was performed. The possible response codes are as follows:

```
200: Successful request (at least one placemark was returned).
400: Bad request (the server was unable to understand the request).
500: Server error (an unknown internal error occurred).
601: Missing query. This means the q parameter was not specified (or was an empty string).
602: Unknown address. This means that the request was performed but no placemarks were found.
603: Unavailable address. The given address could not be returned due to legal or contractual reasons.
610: An invalid Google Maps API key was specified.
620: Too many queries have been performed using the given API key.
```

The problem is because of the values of latitude and longitude.

Comment: ok. thanks a ton to you all. I was testing this on my simulator that is why I was getting these longitude and latitude values. I have corrected the values and found the correct results. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using invalid coordinates. Try this.
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/geo?json&ll=35.670392,139.775844&sensor=false

Comment: Also, I wanted to ask that when I try to install my app, it shows to me that "This application requires the following module, which is not installed: net_rim_json_org". When I add this package to my app and try to sign it, it gives me the  error of Duplicate JSONArray.java . This, I believe, is because I have Blackberry JDE version 7.0 installed. And I have found that the net_rim_json_org package is included in version 7 of the blackberry OS. And the Blackberry device I am using, Blackberry Curve 8520, has version 5 installed. What should I do now? Please help. Thanks.